# What is the function of this sed shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I was reading [this example](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/example-cluster.html) about setting up a cluster with pgpool and Watchdog and decided to give it a try as an exercise.

I'm far from being a master of shell scripting, but I could follow the documentation and modify it according to the settings of my virtual machines. But I don't get what is the purpose of the following snippet:

```
if [ ${PGVERSION} -ge 12 ]; then
    sed -i -e \"\\\$ainclude_if_exists = '$(echo ${RECOVERYCONF} | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g')'\" \
           -e \"/^include_if_exists = '$(echo ${RECOVERYCONF} | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g')'/d\" ${DEST_NODE_PGDATA}/postgresql.conf
fi
```

In my case PGVERSION will be `12` (so the script will execute the code after the condition), RECOVERYCONF is `/usr/local/pgsql/data/myrecovery.conf` and DEST_NODE_PGDATA is `/usr/local/pgsql/data`.

I get (please excuse and correct me if I'm wrong) that -e indicates that a script comes next, the $(some commands) part evaluates the expression and returns the result, and that the sed regular expression indicates that the '/'s will be replaced by \/ (forward slash and slash). What is puzzling me are the `"\\\$ainclude_if_exists ="` and `"/^include_if_exists"` parts, I don't know what they mean or what are they intended for, nor how they interact. Also, the -e after the first sed regular expression is confusing me.

If you are interested in the context, those commands are near the end of the `/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/recovery_1st_stage` example script.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: 1) you can just compare $`{DEST_NODE_PGDATA}/postgresql.conf` before and after running this command (so `cp ${DEST_NODE_PGDATA}/postgresql.conf
 {DEST_NODE_PGDATA}/postgresql.conf.bak` and then `diff ${DEST_NODE_PGDATA}/postgresql.conf*`. ....

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are generally not considered on-topic here. See [How to deal with questions of the type "I don't understand how this code works"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works) on [meta].

Comment: 2) You can dig down further by looking at the flow with the debug option set, i.e. `set -x` (or even `set -vx` and `set +x` (`set +vx`) to turn it of. 3 ) you "drill down" and "explode" each statement to its component parts, like "what does `echo ${RECOVERYCONF} | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g'` produce as output, what does it feed into, what does **that** produce, etc? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your suggestion, that helped me to get what the script was doing.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Sorrry, if I broke a rule. I had spent a couple of hours and couldn't find any explanation. I tried to narrow the question to the part that interested me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tiny representation of the same code:

```
sed -i -e '$amyvalue = foo' -e '/^myvalue = foo/d' myfile.txt
```

The first sed expression is:

```
$                  # On the last line        
 a                 # Append the following text
  myvalue = foo    # (text to be appended)
```

The second is:

```
/                  # On lines matching regex..
 ^myvalue = foo    # (regex to match)
               /   # (end of regex)
                d  # ..delete the line
```

So it deletes any `myvalue = foo` that may already exists, and then adds one such line at the end. The point is just to ensure that you have exactly one line, by A. adding the line if it's missing, B. not duplicate the line if it already exists.

The rest of the expression is merely complicated by the fact that this snippet uses variables and is embedded in a double quoted string that's being passed to a different host via `ssh`, and therefore requires some additional escaping both of the variables and of the quotes.

Comment: Been trying to replicate this. In my case it would be
`gsed -i -e \"$aincludeifexists=$(echo '/usr/local/bin/pqsql/' | gsed '/\//\\\//g')\" -e \"/^include_if_exists = '$(echo '/usr/local/bin/pqsql/' gsed '/\//\\\//g')'/d\" myfile.txt` 
Forgot to say I was working under FreeBSD, so I always specify I want GNU-Sed. 
I'm still getting errors in the way of `-e Unkown command "`
Sorry if I'm missing something

Comment: Sorry about the other comment, I just noticed that and didn't want to bother you but I guess it was too late :c

Comment: The syntax of the snippet is not valid by itself because it's embedded in a double quoted string as mentioned. You need to un-escape it if you want to run it independently: `sed -i -e "\$ainclude_if_exists = '$(echo '/usr/local/bin/pqsql/' | sed 's/\//\\\//g')'" -e "/^include_if_exists = '$(echo '/usr/local/bin/pqsql/' | sed 's/\//\\\//g')'/d" myfile.txt`

Comment: Now I get it! I was messed with all the escapes. I am correct if I guess that the sed part was to add the necessary scapes so it could be written to the file in the other machine without trouble? Marking the question as solved. Thanks for your help, you are great!

Comment: Basically, yes. You can see that `sed -i "s/.*/hello world/" file.txt` is a valid command, but `ssh localhost "sed -i "s/.*/hello world/" file.txt"` fails. Conversely, `ssh localhost "sed -i \"s/.*/hello world/\" file.txt"` works, but just copying the command without the context (`sed -i \"s/.*/hello world/\" file.txt`) fails